# XSLT sorting on multiples levels

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

Good evening everybody,

I've created a little program to be able to sort all the audio files contained in a directory (and all the sub-directories also). I'm gathering all the information in C# in order to produce the following XML file (the XML below is a stripped down version, i deleted all the attributes not needed here):

```
<Directory Name="Compilations" >
  <Directory Name="Compil - 2010" >
    <File MediaTitle="4 Min" MediaAlbum="AA" MediaYear="2010" MediaArtists="Madonna" />
    <File MediaTitle="Beggin" MediaAlbum="AA" MediaYear="2010" MediaArtists="Madcon" />
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

And i wanted the following result:

```
<MediaYear Year="2010">
  <MediaArtists Artist="Madonna">
    <MediaAlbum Album="AA">
      <File MediaTitle="4 Min" MediaAlbum="AA" MediaYear="2010" MediaArtists="Madonna" />
    </MediaAlbum>
  </MediaArtists>
  <MediaArtists Artist="Madcon">
    <MediaAlbum Album="AA">
      <File MediaTitle="Beggin" MediaAlbum="AA" MediaYear="2010" MediaArtists="Madcon" />
    </MediaAlbum>
  </MediaArtists>
</MediaYear>
```

All the "File" occurrences should be sorted of the following manner:

- Year
- Artist
- Album

The XSLT code, I am using is as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key match="File[@MediaYear != 0]" name="MediaYears" use="@MediaYear"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="//File[generate-id(.)= generate-id(key('MediaYears', @MediaYear)[1])]">

      <xsl:sort select="@MediaYear"/>

      <MediaYear>

        <xsl:attribute name="Year">

          <xsl:value-of select="@MediaYear"/>

        </xsl:attribute>

        <xsl:for-each select="key('MediaYears', @MediaYear)">

          <xsl:copy>

            <xsl:copy-of select="node() | @* | node()"/>

          </xsl:copy>

        </xsl:for-each>

      </MediaYear>

    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this code only applies to the first level of sorting, so i wanted to add the second level by adding this piece of code:

```
<xsl:key match="//File[@MediaArtists != '']" name="AlbumArtists" use="@MediaArtists"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:variable name="VPass1">

    <xsl:call-template name="YearProcess"/>

  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:apply-templates mode="Artist_Display" select="ext:node-set($VPass1)"/>

</xsl:template>
```

and i changed the existing xsl:template to the following:

```
<xsl:template match="/" name="YearProcess" mode="Year_Display">
```

and i added the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="/" mode="Artist_Display">

  <xsl:for-each select="//File[generate-id(.)= generate-id(key('AlbumArtists', @MediaArtists)[1])]">

    <xsl:sort select="ancestor::MediaYear[1]/@Year"/>

    <xsl:sort select="@MediaArtists"/>

    <MediaArtists>

      <xsl:attribute name="AlbumArtists">

        <xsl:value-of select="@MediaArtists"/>

      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:attribute name="AlbumYear">

        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::MediaYear[1]/@Year"/>

      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:for-each select="key('AlbumArtists', @MediaArtists)">

        <xsl:copy>

          <!--<xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::MediaYear[1]"/>-->

          <xsl:copy-of select="node() | @* | node()"/>

        </xsl:copy>

      </xsl:for-each>

    </MediaArtists>

  </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

And i'm not getting the expected result, i'm pretty new to XSLT and forgive me if the answer already exists, i searched but i'm a little lost and i don't know exactly what to search.

I'm pretty sure it's not very clear and if needed the code is available here :

https://github.com/jaguar0076/FileManager/blob/master/FileManager/Stylesheet.xslt

I don't know where to go and maybe the muenchian method isn't the best way to achieve what i want.

Thank you for any help you can provide,

Rodrigue

Edit: Title changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution which is based on creating three keys.

```
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key match="File[@MediaYear != 0]" name="MediaYears" use="@MediaYear"/>

  <!-- the following key has been designed on the assumption that MediaYear never contains a space-->
  <xsl:key match="File[@MediaArtists != '']" name="MediaArtists" use="concat(@MediaYear, ' ', @MediaArtists)"/>

  <!-- the following key has been designed on the assumption that MediaYear never contains a space
  AND MediaArtists never contains a %-->
  <xsl:key match="File[@MediaAlbum != '']" name="MediaAlbum" use="concat(@MediaYear, ' ', @MediaArtists, '%', @MediaAlbum)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="//File[generate-id(.)= generate-id(key('MediaYears', @MediaYear)[1])]">

      <xsl:sort select="@MediaYear"/>

      <MediaYear Year="{@MediaYear}">

        <xsl:variable name="MediaYear" select="@MediaYear"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="//File[@MediaYear=$MediaYear and generate-id(.)= generate-id(key('MediaArtists', concat(@MediaYear, ' ', @MediaArtists))[1])]">

          <xsl:sort select="@MediaArtists"/>
          <MediaArtists Artist="{@MediaArtists}">
            <xsl:variable name="MediaArtists" select="@MediaArtists"/>

            <xsl:for-each select="//File[@MediaYear=$MediaYear and @MediaArtists=$MediaArtists and generate-id(.)= generate-id(key('MediaAlbum', concat(@MediaYear, ' ', @MediaArtists, '%', @MediaAlbum))[1])]">
              <xsl:sort select="@MediaAlbum"/>

              <MediaAlbum Album="{@MediaAlbum}">
                <xsl:variable name="MediaAlbum" select="@MediaAlbum"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="//File[@MediaYear=$MediaYear and @MediaArtists=$MediaArtists and @MediaAlbum=$MediaAlbum]">
                  <xsl:copy>

                    <xsl:copy-of select="node() | @* | node()"/>

                  </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </MediaAlbum>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </MediaArtists>
        </xsl:for-each>

      </MediaYear>

    </xsl:for-each>


  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your processor supports EXSLT (as it seems from your code), you can use the set:distinct() function instead of Muenchian grouping. For example, something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets" 
extension-element-prefixes="set">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="fileByYear" match="File" use="@MediaYear" />
<xsl:key name="fileByArtistYear" match="File" use="concat(@MediaArtists, '|', @MediaYear)" />
<xsl:key name="fileByAlbumArtistYear" match="File" use="concat(@MediaAlbum, '|', @MediaArtists, '|', @MediaYear)" />

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(//File/@MediaYear)">
<xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
<MediaYear Year="{.}">
    <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(key('fileByYear', .)/@MediaArtists)">
    <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
    <MediaArtists Artist="{.}">
        <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(key('fileByArtistYear', concat(., '|', ../@MediaYear))/@MediaAlbum)">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        <MediaAlbum Album="{.}">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('fileByAlbumArtistYear', concat(., '|', ../@MediaArtists, '|', ../@MediaYear))">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </MediaAlbum>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </MediaArtists>
    </xsl:for-each>
</MediaYear>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that if your directories are already year-specific, you could use that in order to save some processing here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, unfortunately Visual Studio seems to not be able to deal with the following declaration:

    xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets" 
    extension-element-prefixes="set">

I have an error about the namespace, so i will use @polly-shaw answer to avoid unnecessary research or maybe you have an idea about this error ?

Thanks

Sorry about the multiple edit i'm not use with the Shift-Enter shortcut....

Comment: @user3123948 That is strange. Have you tried changing `extension-element-prefixes="set"` to `exclude-result-prefixes="set"`? What exactly is the error message you get?

Comment: Seems like I've found something: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950776.aspx

Comment: I have the following error (it is an approximate translation from french):

Cannot find a script object or extensions associated with the namespace "http://exslt.org/sets"

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I tried with the exclude-result-prefixes but i have the same error, sorry i forgot to mention i'm using VS Studio 2010 Pro

Comment: @RodrigueFidis I am afraid I know nothing about Visual Studio. It seems very strange that it would bulk at a namespace. I could understand if it errored on account of an unsupported function, but a namespace? Considering that you had no problems with `xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"`, and that `xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"` is the [officially recommended declaration](http://www.exslt.org/set/index.html), I am afraid I have run out of ideas

Comment: I found that Visual Studio 2010 processor (XslCompiledTransform) does not implement any EXSLT function except common:node-set()) and it seems like there is no easy way to use other XSLT processors in Visual Studio. Thank you anyway, your code was really interesting.